# Python not finding common element in lists

Tags: python, string, list

I'm building a program in Python 3 that needs to go through two lists and count how many times the elements of the first list appear in the second. However, even if I plug in two lists that are hard-coded to have common elements, Python says the list doesn't have any common elements.

Here's a minimal, runnable version of my program:

```
strings = ["I sell","seashells","by the","seashore"]
ngramSet = ["by the"]
for ngram in ngramSet:
    print("Ngram: \"" + str(ngram) + "\"")
    # Should return "by the" twice where it appears twice.
    occurrences = [element for element in strings if element is ngram]
    print("Occurrences: " + str(occurrences))
    count = len(occurrences)
    print("Number of times N-gram appears in string" + str(count))
```

Output:

```
Ngram: "by the"
Occurrences: []
Number of times N-gram appears in string0
```

Comment: first for loops through your set, second for loops through every single letter.

Comment: It returns result for me.

Comment: Don't use `is` to compare strings for equality, use `==`, `is` is for *identity comparisons*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is correct. The only problem is within your `lambda`, where you compare the two strings using `is`. You should be comparing them using `==` because you are doing equality comparison.

Comment: This is correct, but I don't see a lambda

Answer (score 1):

[`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) was made for this!

```
import collections

strings = ["I sell","seashells","by the","seashore"]
ngramSet = ["by the"]
strings_counter = collections.Counter(strings)

for string in ngramSet:
    print(string, strings_counter[string])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it very short and clear, there are multiple ways but here is one:

```
strings = ["I sell","seashells","by the","seashore"]
ngramSet = ["by the"]

# Built in count function
for x in ngramSet:
        print (x, " -> ", strings.count(x))

# Or make it a one-liner
print ([(arg, strings.count(arg)) for arg in ngramSet])
```

Or you could simply use your code because it seems to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get common elements, then try sets:

```
list(set(strings).intersection(set(ngramSet)))
```